# Enumerate with two separate numbers

Tags: enumerate

I'm trying to generate a numbered list of names using the [register system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genealogical_numbering_systems#Register_System) of genealogical numbering.  It should look something like the following:

```
1    (i)  John Smith.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
          adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 
          labore et dolore magna aliqua. ...
    (ii)  Ann Smith.
   (iii)  James Smith.
2   (iv)  Eliza Smith.
```

... with the two types of numerals aligned (right aligned for the Roman ones, left for the Arabic).  I can do this with a tabular `\begin{tabular}{lrp{\somewidth}}`, but then I have to work out the correct column widths, which is a nuisance; I can't get round this by using the `X` specifier from the `tabularx` package because very often I'll want to span pages, and the workarounds for that are all a bit tedious.  In any case, it feels like the right place for an `enumerate`-like environment

My current best idea is to automate the numbering in something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text only
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[1\quad(i)] John Smith. \lipsum[1]
\item[(ii)] Ann Smith.
\item[(iii)] James Smith.
\item[2\quad(iv)] James Smith.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

But then I don't get alignment of the Arabic numbers.  Any ideas?

Comment: I just updated my answer with some other settings taking care of the case in which the "outer" list counter has more than one digit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions from @Gonzalo Medina and @cfr are ingenious, but I can't help but feel the nested enumeration is wrong.  Logically it's a single list, not a list of lists.  I've spent the morning looking for a better solution and think I have one: use the more primitive `list` environment instead of `enumerate`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}  % For dummy text only
\newcounter{childcounter}
\newenvironment{children}{
  \begin{list}{\childxref\hfill(\roman{childcounter})\quad}{
    \usecounter{childcounter}\setlength\labelsep{0em}
    \setlength\labelwidth{5em}\setlength\leftmargin{5em}
    \newcommand{\child}[1][]{\def\childxref{##1}\item}}
}{\end{list}}
\begin{document}
\begin{children}
\child[1] John Smith. \lipsum[1]
\child Ann Smith.
\child James Smith.
\child[2] James Smith.
\end{children}
\end{document}
```

The normal use I anticipate for the optional argument to `\child` would be something like `\child[\ref{james}]`, so I'd probably define it to take the label name directly:

```
\newcommand{\child}[1][]{%
  \def\childxref{\ifstrempty{##1}{}{\ref{##1}}}\item}}
```

which also requires `\usepackage{etoolbox}` to define `\ifstrempty`.  Then I can just write `\child[james]` provided that elsewhere I have a `\label{james}`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one option using the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlist{menumerate}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[menumerate,1]{label=\arabic*}
\setlist[menumerate,2]{label=(\roman*)}

\begin{document}
\begin{menumerate}
\item\begin{menumerate}
\item John Smith. \lipsum[1]
\item Ann Smith.
\item James Smith.
\end{menumerate}
\item
\begin{menumerate}[resume]
\item James Smith.
\end{menumerate}
\end{menumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need to increase the spacing between the Arabic and Roman numerals, you can use something like

```
\newlist{menumerate}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[menumerate,1]{label=\arabic*,wide,leftmargin=*,labelsep=20pt}
\setlist[menumerate,2]{label=(\roman*),labelsep=5pt}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlist{menumerate}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[menumerate,1]{label=\arabic*,wide,leftmargin=*,labelsep=20pt}
\setlist[menumerate,2]{label=(\roman*),labelsep=5pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{menumerate}
\item\begin{menumerate}
\item John Smith. \lipsum[1]
\item Ann Smith.
\item James Smith.
\end{menumerate}
\item
\begin{menumerate}[resume,start=99]% start value just for the example
\item James Smith.
\end{menumerate}
\end{menumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the inner list is always supposed to continue the numbering the `resume` option can be included in the `\setlist`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlist{menumerate}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[menumerate,1]{label=\arabic*,wide,leftmargin=*,labelsep=20pt}
\setlist[menumerate,2]{label=(\roman*),labelsep=5pt,resume}

\begin{document}
\begin{menumerate}
\item
  \begin{menumerate} 
  \item John Smith. \lipsum[1]
  \item Ann Smith.
  \item James Smith.
  \end{menumerate}
\item
  \begin{menumerate}
  \item James Smith.
  \end{menumerate}
\item
  \begin{menumerate}
  \item Henry Smith.
  \end{menumerate}
\end{menumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And perhaps, even better, something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlist{menumerate}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[menumerate,1]{
  label=\arabic*,
  leftmargin=50pt,
  labelsep=15pt,
  labelwidth=20pt,
  align=left
}
\setlist[menumerate,2]{label=(\roman*),labelsep=5pt,resume}

\begin{document}

\begin{menumerate}
\item
  \begin{menumerate} 
  \item John Smith. \lipsum[1]
  \item Ann Smith.
  \item James Smith.
  \end{menumerate}
\item
  \begin{menumerate}
  \item James Smith.
  \end{menumerate}
\item
  \begin{menumerate}
  \item Henry Smith.
  \end{menumerate}
\item
  \begin{menumerate}
  \item Henry Smith.
  \end{menumerate}
\item
  \begin{menumerate}
  \item Henry Smith.
  \end{menumerate}
\item
  \begin{menumerate}
  \item Henry Smith.
  \end{menumerate}
\item
  \begin{menumerate}
  \item Henry Smith.
  \end{menumerate}
\item
  \begin{menumerate}
  \item Henry Smith.
  \end{menumerate}
\item
  \begin{menumerate}
  \item Henry Smith.
  \end{menumerate}
\item
  \begin{menumerate}
  \item Henry Smith.
  \end{menumerate}
\end{menumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Two problems with this.  First, it doesn't seem possible to not put an Arabic number on the first entry.  The Arabic numbers are simply cross-references to later sections, so it's quite common for the first name not to have one.  Second and more cosmetically, because it uses a nested enumeration, it's hard to stop there from being extra spacing before an Arabic-numbered line.  (This can be fixed with careful setting of the spacings.)

Comment: @richard For the first "issue", you can use an empty optional argument for `\item`, as in `\begin{menumerate}
\item[]
  \begin{menumerate} 
  \item John Smith. \lipsum[1]
  \end{menumerate}
\item
  \begin{menumerate} 
  \item James Smith.
  \end{menumerate}
\end{menumerate}`

Comment: @richard For the second one, if I understood correctly, you can use `nosep` as in `\setlist[menumerate,1]{
  label=\arabic*,
  leftmargin=50pt,
  labelsep=15pt,
  labelwidth=20pt,
  align=left,
  nosep
}
\setlist[menumerate,2]{label=(\roman*),labelsep=5pt,resume}`

Answer (score 4):

Something like this? I define a new environment `geneology`. Within this environment, `\nextgene` is used to indicate that the outer counter should increment. Otherwise, just use `\item` as usual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,enumitem}
\newlist{geneo}{enumerate}{1}
\newlist{geneol}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[geneo,1]{label=\arabic*, align=left}
\setlist[geneol,1]{label=(\roman*)}
\newenvironment{geneology}{%
  \begin{geneo}\item\begin{geneol}%
}{%
  \end{geneol}\end{geneo}%
}
\newcommand*\nextgene{%
  \end{geneol}\item\begin{geneol}[resume]%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{geneology}
  \item John Smith. \lipsum[1]
  \item Ann Smith.
  \item James Smith.
  \nextgene
  \item James Smith.
\end{geneology}
\end{document}
```

[image: geneology]